# Cocoa: get window in windowDidLoad in controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

My `NSWindowController` has this code:

```
- (id)init {
    [self initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];       
    [self loadWindow];
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSWindow *window = [self window];
    NSAssert(window != nil, @"Can’t get window!");

    // do some stuff    
}
```

The `NSAssert`fails.

Why?

How can I get the window?

Comment: Connected properly in the nib?

Comment: @WTP: What does that mean? How can I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here. Firstly, your initialiser is missing the assignment to `self`:

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
    if(self)
    {
        [self loadWindow];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Secondly, and the probable reason that your assertion is failing, is that you have not connected the `window` outlet of **File's Owner** in your nib file to the window object. This means that your window controller doesn't know what object the window property points to.

If you don't understand how to set outlets in Interface Builder then you have a lot of learning to do and you should do a [simple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611) before you do anything else, because understanding how outlets and actions work is fundamental to being able to program with Cocoa.

Comment: Ah, this was somehow not straight forward to me. I thought that if I use `initWithWindowNibName`, i.e. the controller loads and creates the window, it is obvious that the controller owns the window and can set its own `window` property to it. Also, how would I use the same window NIB for other controllers then?

Comment: You can re-use a nib as often as you like, as long as the class name assigned to `File's Owner` in the nib is the same class that you're using as the owner of the nib (or the owner is a subclass). You can certainly instantiate multiple different window controllers from the same nib. The nib is just an archived graph of objects, when you load it, those archived objects are instantiated as new objects. You won't get duplicate objects if you load the nib a second time with a different controller.

Comment: But what if I want different window controllers with different class names to use the same NIB? Why does the NIB need to know at all about the controller?

Comment: It doesn't, really. Setting the class name of the nib allows IB to display the available outlets and actions for File's Owner. The actual connection of an object to the File's Owner placeholder takes place within the nib loading system, using the `instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:` method of `NSNib`, but that doesn't matter in practice. What I would suggest is setting the class name to `NSWindowController`, because if all your controllers are subclasses of `NSWindowController`, the `window` outlet will always be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that we had to link the File Owner's window to the NSWindowController in IB!

Comment: @RobKeniger's comment regarding the matching class name in `File's Owner` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't there a

```
self = [super init];
```

in your

```
- (id)init {
[self initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];       
[self loadWindow];
return self;
```

}

Comment: No. The designated initialiser is `initWithWindowNibName:`, but you're right that you should call it on `super`.